# Enviar email dentro do if com phpmailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

Já criei dentro do meu servidor uma pasta **phpmailer** com as classes **PHPMailer.php e SMTP.php**.
Agora tenho este código para inserir na tabela da base de dados:

```
$data = isset($_POST["DataRegisto"]) ? $_POST["DataRegisto"] : '';   
$contacto = isset($_POST["Contacto"]) ? $_POST["Contacto"] : '';    
$telefone = isset($_POST["Telefone"]) ? $_POST["Telefone"] : '';
$crianca = isset($_POST["NomeCrianca"]) ? $_POST["NomeCrianca"] : ''; 
$nascimento = isset($_POST["DataNasc"]) ? $_POST["DataNasc"] : ''; 
$visita = isset($_POST["Visita"]) ? $_POST["Visita"] : '';   
$datavisita = isset($_POST["DataVisita"]) ? $_POST["DataVisita"] : '';
$observacao1 = isset($_POST["Observacao1"]) ? $_POST["Observacao1"] : '';    

$sql = "INSERT INTO InscricoesInf (`DataRegisto`,`Nome`,`Contacto`,`Telefone`,`NomeCrianca`,`DataNasc`,`Visita`,`DataVisita`,`Observacao1`)   VALUES('$data','xxxxxx','$contacto','$telefone','$crianca','$nascimento','$visita','$datavisita','$observacao1')";

$qr = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$conn->close();
```

Pretendia que sempre que fizesse uma nova inserção na tabela da base de dados enviasse uma email avisar a responsável por este assunto.

**Com as soluções apresentadas desenvolvi o meu código, está a inserir na base de dados, mas não está a enviar o email:**

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

class Mail
{
    public function sendMail($crianca, $contacto, $nascimento, $message)
    {
        require './PHPMailer';
        require './SMTP';
        require './Exception';

        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        try {
            // Server settings
            $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Define o mail para usar o SMTP
            $mail->Host = 'smtp.hotmail.com';                     // Define o host do e-mail
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Permite autenticação SMTP 
            $mail->Username = 'xxxxxxxxxxx@hotmail.com';              // Conta de e-mail que enviará o e-mail
            $mail->Password = 'xxxxxxx';                       // Senha da conta de e-mail
            $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Permite encriptação TLS
            $mail->Port = 587;                                    // Porta TCP que irá se conectar
            $mail->SMTPOptions = array( // Configuração adicional, não obrigatória (caso de erro de ssl)
                'ssl' => array(
                    'verify_peer' => false,
                    'verify_peer_name' => false,
                    'allow_self_signed' => true
                )
            );

             // Recipients
            $mail->setFrom('xxxxxxxx@hotmail.com', 'Título do e-mail, ou assunto'); // Define o remetente
            $mail->addAddress('qualidade@xxxxxxxxx.xxxxx', 'Contato Site');             // Define o destinário

            // Content
            $mail->isHTML(true); // Define o formato do e-mail para HTML
            $mail->Subject = 'Contato feito pelo site';
            $mail->Body = "
                        <html>
                        <head>
                        </head>
                        <body>
                        <h2>Pedido de Informação</h2>

                        <table>
                          <tr>
                            <th>Nome</th>
                            <th>Telefone</th>
                            <th>Data Nascimento</th>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td>$crianca</td> 
                            <td>$contacto</td>
                            <td>$nascimento</td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>

                        <h2>Novo registo nos pedidos de informação./h2>

                        <p>$message</p>

                        </body>
                        </html>";
            $mail->send(); // Envia o e-mail
            return true;
        } catch (Exception $e) { // Se capturar exceção retorna false
            return false;
        }
    }
}

$data = isset($_POST["DataRegisto"]) ? $_POST["DataRegisto"] : '';   
$contacto = isset($_POST["Contacto"]) ? $_POST["Contacto"] : '';    
$telefone = isset($_POST["Telefone"]) ? $_POST["Telefone"] : '';
$crianca = isset($_POST["NomeCrianca"]) ? $_POST["NomeCrianca"] : ''; 
$nascimento = isset($_POST["DataNasc"]) ? $_POST["DataNasc"] : ''; 
$visita = isset($_POST["Visita"]) ? $_POST["Visita"] : '';   
$datavisita = isset($_POST["DataVisita"]) ? $_POST["DataVisita"] : '';
$observacao1 = isset($_POST["Observacao1"]) ? $_POST["Observacao1"] : '';    

$sql = "INSERT INTO InscricoesInf (`DataRegisto`,`Nome`,`Contacto`,`Telefone`,`NomeCrianca`,`DataNasc`,`Visita`,`DataVisita`,`Observacao1`)
VALUES ('$data','xxxxxx','$contacto','$telefone','$crianca','$nascimento','$visita','$datavisita','$observacao1')";

if ($conn->query($sql)) { 
    $Mail = new Mail();
    $Mail->sendEmail('Seu nome', 'Telefone', 'Data Nascimento', 'Mensagem do e-mail');
    $conn->close();
} else {
    echo 'Erro';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para enviar e-mail com o PHPMailer você pode definir uma estrutura básica que irá permitir o envio de e-mails via conexão *SMTP* ou *POP3*.

Antes de começar siga o tutorial abaixo:

1. Baixe a última versão (nesse caso é 6.0.5) do [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).
2. Descompacte o arquivo baixado e mantenha somente esses arquivos junto com a pasta `src`:

   - Exception.php, OAuth.php, PHPMailer.php, POP3.php e SMTP.php;

Agora vamos ao que realmente interessa, o envio de e-mail.

Vamos definir uma estrutura básica ao nosso projeto.

```
/seu_projeto/
   |--app/
   |    |--class/
   |    |       |--PHPMailer/
   |    |       |            |--src/
   |    |       |            |     |Exception.php
   |    |       |            |     |OAuth.php
   |    |       |            |     |PHPMailer.php
   |    |       |            |     |POP3.php
   |    |       |            |     |SMTP.php
   |    |Mail.php
```

Com isso já podemos realizar o script de envio de e-mail utilizando a classe `Mail.php`. No exemplo para um formulário básico.

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

class Mail
{
    public function sendMail($name, $email, $phone, $subject, $message)
    {
        require 'PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
        require 'PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';
        require 'PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';

        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        try {
            // Server settings
            $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Define o mail para usar o SMTP
            $mail->Host = 'smtp.dominio.net';                     // Define o host do e-mail
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Permite autenticação SMTP 
            $mail->Username = 'exemplo@dominio.net';              // Conta de e-mail que enviará o e-mail
            $mail->Password = 'exemplo123';                       // Senha da conta de e-mail
            $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Permite encriptação TLS
            $mail->Port = 587;                                    // Porta TCP que irá se conectar
            $mail->SMTPOptions = array( // Configuração adicional, não obrigatória (caso de erro de ssl)
                'ssl' => array(
                    'verify_peer' => false,
                    'verify_peer_name' => false,
                    'allow_self_signed' => true
                )
            );

            // Recipients
            $mail->setFrom('seuemail@gmail.com', 'Título do e-mail, ou assunto'); // Define o remetente
            $mail->addAddress('aleatoria@gmail.com', 'Contato Site');             // Define o destinário

            // Content
            $mail->isHTML(true); // Define o formato do e-mail para HTML
            $mail->Subject = 'Contato feito pelo site';
            $mail->Body = "
                        <html>
                        <head>
                        </head>
                        <body>
                        <h2>Coloque aqui o seu assunto</h2>

                        <table>
                          <tr>
                            <th>Nome</th>
                            <th>E-mail</th>
                            <th>Telefone</th>
                            <th>Assunto</th>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td>$name</td>
                            <td>$email</td>  
                            <td>$phone</td>
                            <td>$subject</td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>

                        <h2>Conteúdo da mensagem</h2>

                        <p>$message</p>

                        </body>
                        </html>";
            if (!$mail->send()) {
               echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
               return true;
            } else {
               echo "Mensagem enviada";
               return false;
            } 
        } catch (Exception $e) { // Se capturar exceção retorna false
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Para realizar o envio de e-mail se a sua conexão foi com sucesso você poderia usar uma estrutura parecida com essa:

```
 ...    

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    $Mail = new Mail();
    $Mail->sendEmail('Seu nome', 'Email', 'Telefone', 'Assunto do e-mail', 'Mensagem do e-mail');
    $conn->close();
} else {
    echo 'Erro';
}
```

**Referências**

- [Documentação do PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)
- [Fórum do PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues)

Comment: pode verificar a edição que fiz na pergunta com o código desenvolvido seguindo o seu exemplo?

Comment: Coloca essa linha de código e vê se ele mostra alguma mensagem de erro: `$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;`. Outra coisa, lembra de seguir a estrutura das pastas conforme coloquei no meu exemplo, é essencial para que o mesmo funcione.

Comment: masvo meu código está correto? Não deteta nenhum erro? A estrutura das pastas está correta

Comment: @Iniciante, atualizei a minha resposta na parte da classe Mail onde é realizado o envio de e-mail. Verifica agora e vê se mostra mensagem de erro.

Comment: podemos falar no chat só para tirar umas dúvidas que penso que o problema estará aí?

Comment: Sim, é possível

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83063/discussion-between-iniciante-and-joao-pedro-schmitz).

Comment: já consegui resolver o problema e já envia emails

Comment: Que bom que deu certo! Se a minha resposta ajudou por favor considere dar um voto positivo e marcar como a correta!

Answer (score 0):

O PHPMailer é uma classe pronta para envio de e-mails só tem que integrar este código no código da base de dados para enviar um e-mail com poucas opções e simples. (Isto só funcionará se o seu servidor tiver permissão para envio de emails por SMTP)

```
 // Incluir phpmailer.php localizado na pasta x
 require_once("x/PHPMailer.php");

 // Inicia a classe PHPMailer
 $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

 $mail->IsSMTP(); // Define que a mensagem será SMTP

 try {
 $mail->Host = 'smtp.dominio.com'; // Endereço do servidor SMTP (Autenticação, utilize o host smtp.dominio.com)
 $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;  // Usar autenticação SMTP
 $mail->Port       = 587; //  Usar 587 porta SMTP
 $mail->Username = 'usuário de smtp'; // Usuário do servidor SMTP 
 $mail->Password = 'senha de smtp'; // Senha do servidor SMTP 

 //Define o remetente
 // =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=    
 $mail->SetFrom('seu@gmail.com', 'Nome'); //Seu e-mail
 $mail->AddReplyTo('seu@gmail.com', 'Nome'); //Seu e-mail
 $mail->Subject = 'Assunto';//Assunto do e-mail

 //Email da responsável
 $mail->AddAddress('e-mail@gmail.com', '');

 //Define o corpo do email
 $mail->MsgHTML('corpo do email'); 

 $mail->Send();
 echo "Mensagem enviada com sucesso</p>\n";

//caso apresente algum erro é apresentado abaixo com essa exceção.
}catch (phpmailerException $e) {
  echo $e->errorMessage(); //Mensagem de erro costumizada pelo PHPMailer
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro dentro da pasta do meu projecto criei uma pasta com o nome **phpmailer** e dentro dessa pasta coloquei estes dois arquivos: `class.phpmailer.php` e `class.smtp.php`, que fiz download no site que deixo no fim da resposta.

Depois no arquivo php onde faço a inserção dos dados tenho este código:

```
<?php 
require ("phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");
require ("phpmailer/class.smtp.php");

# Inicia a classe PHPMailer
$mail = new PHPMailer();

# Define os dados do servidor e tipo de conexão
$mail->IsSMTP(); // Define que a mensagem será SMTP
$mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; # Endereço do servidor SMTP, na WebHS basta usar localhost caso a conta de email esteja na mesma máquina de onde esta a correr este código, caso contrário altere para o seu desejado ex: mail.nomedoseudominio.pt
$mail->Port = 587; // Porta TCP para a conexão
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false; // Utiliza TLS Automaticamente se disponível
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; # Usar autenticação SMTP - Sim
$mail->Username = 'xxxxxxx@gmail.com'; # Login de e-mail
$mail->Password = 'xxxxxxxx'; // # Password do e-mail
# Define o remetente (você)
$mail->From = "xxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com"; # Seu e-mail
$mail->FromName = "xxxxxxxx"; // Seu nome
# Define os destinatário(s)
$mail->AddAddress('xxxxxxxx@xxxxxxxxx.xx', 'xxxxxxxxx'); # Os campos podem ser substituidos por variáveis
#$mail->AddAddress('webmaster@nomedoseudominio.pt'); # Caso queira receber uma copia
#$mail->AddCC('pessoa2@dominio.pt', 'Pessoa Nome 2'); # Copia
#$mail->AddBCC('pessoa3@dominio.pt', 'Pessoa Nome 3'); # Cópia Oculta
# Define os dados técnicos da Mensagem
$mail->IsHTML(true); # Define que o e-mail será enviado como HTML
#$mail->CharSet = 'iso-8859-1'; # Charset da mensagem (opcional)
# Define a mensagem (Texto e Assunto)
$mail->Subject = "Teste"; # Assunto da mensagem
$mail->Body = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$mail->AltBody = "Este é o corpo da mensagem de teste, somente Texto! \r\n :)";

# Define os anexos (opcional)
#$mail->AddAttachment("c:/temp/documento.pdf", "documento.pdf"); # Insere um anexo
# Envia o e-mail
$enviado = $mail->Send();

# Limpa os destinatários e os anexos
$mail->ClearAllRecipients();
$mail->ClearAttachments();

$data = isset($_POST["DataRegisto"]) ? $_POST["DataRegisto"] : ''; 
$contacto = isset($_POST["Contacto"]) ? $_POST["Contacto"] : ''; 
$telefone = isset($_POST["Telefone"]) ? $_POST["Telefone"] : ''; 
$crianca = isset($_POST["NomeCrianca"]) ? $_POST["NomeCrianca"] : ''; 
$nascimento = isset($_POST["DataNasc"]) ? $_POST["DataNasc"] : ''; 
$visita = isset($_POST["Visita"]) ? $_POST["Visita"] : ''; 
$datavisita = isset($_POST["DataVisita"]) ? $_POST["DataVisita"] : ''; 
$observacao1 = isset($_POST["Observacao1"]) ? $_POST["Observacao1"] : ''; 

$sql = "INSERT INTO InscricoesInf (`DataRegisto`,`Contacto`,`Telefone`,`NomeCrianca`,`DataNasc`,`Visita`,`DataVisita`,`Observacao1`) 
VALUES ('$data','$contacto','$telefone','$crianca','$nascimento','$visita','$datavisita','$observacao1')"; 

if ($conn->query($sql)) { 
if ($enviado) {
echo "E-mail enviado com sucesso!";
} else {
echo "Não foi possível enviar o e-mail.";
echo "<b>Informações do erro:</b> " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}

} else {
   // get the error, throw a message...
}
$conn->close();

?>
```

E desta forma envia o email direitinho. No conteúdo da mensagem têm a possibilidade de melhorar criando tabela ou o que for mais adequado para o que pretendem.

Também deixo aqui o link com o tutorial que segui:

https://www.webhs.pt/tutoriais/nao-funcao-mail-aprenda-usar-phpmailer-smtp-autenticado/